# How turn off spell check in QuillJS (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill, preact

How do you turn off spellcheck in [quill.js](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/) in React?

I found [this GitHub page](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/2225) that shows how disable quill's spellchecker in normal JavaScript:

```
const quill = new Quill('#editor-container')
quill.root.setAttribute('spellcheck', false)
```

However, I can't see how to implement this with a React component.

My React component (Preact actually):

```html
import { h, FunctionalComponent } from 'preact';
import './contentEditor.scss';
import Quill from 'react-quill';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';

interface ContentEditorProps {
  content: string | undefined;
  onChange(value: string): void;
}

const modules = {
  toolbar: [
    [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, false] }],
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'blockquote'],
    [{ color: [] }],
    [{ align: [] }],
    [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
    [{ indent: '-1' }, { indent: '+1' }],
    ['link', 'image'],
  ],
};

const formats = [
  'header',
  'bold',
  'color',
  'italic',
  'underline',
  'strike',
  'blockquote',
  'list',
  'bullet',
  'align',
  'indent',
  'link',
  'image',
];

export const ContentEditor: FunctionalComponent<ContentEditorProps> = ({
  content,
  onChange,
}) => {
  return (
    <Quill
      theme='snow'
      value={content}
      onChange={onChange}
      modules={modules}
      formats={formats}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Never used it but since `quill.root.setAttribute()` sets an element attribute try adding it to the props of `<Quill spellcheck={false}...`

Comment: That was a good idea - in fact, I thought it would work... unfortunately, it didn't. Thanks for the idea, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to access to `Quill` editor, you have to create an `ref` to the `<Quill />` component, then use it to set the attribute. Here is the snippet code:

```js
// For typings
import Quill from "react-quill";
import QuillEditor from "quill"

export const ContentEditor = ({ content, onChange }) => {
  const ref = React.useRef<Quill & { editor: QuillEditor }>(null);

  // Disable spellcheck as component is mounted
  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current?.editor.root.setAttribute("spellcheck", "false");
  }, []);

  return (
    <Quill
      // set the ref to access to quill editor
      ref={ref}
      theme="snow"
      value={content}
      onChange={onChange}
      modules={modules}
      formats={formats}
    />
  );
};
```

I have also made an sample as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-mendel-4g3jw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I'm using quill in [ReactAdmin](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-input-rich-text) where spellcheck somehow was not enabled by default. I enabled it like that `const configureQuill = (quill) => quill.root.setAttribute("spellcheck", "true")`